# Arranging textview item at the centre of a listview and left aligned

Tags: android, listview, textview

I am trying to create list which appears like this

[image]

What I need is each item should start from the same position

my list item XML is like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="ttttttttt "
        android:textColor="@color/info_text_color"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is your layout and you want to add a star centered? or you just want to add a centered Star to an empty listview element?

Comment: @daniel sorry that was a spelling mistake have to start each item from the same position

Comment: you need to set each item from left side or center ??

Comment: each item at the center but left aligned

Comment: i think you need to set margin from left for this... or give fixed width to textview and set gravity left... because with layout gravity center you cant set left gravity to textview having width wrap_content.

Comment: Fixed width will solve my issue but any other better way?

Answer (score 2):

try this `textview`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   //this is change
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"     //this is change
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="ttttttttt "
    android:textColor="@color/info_text_color"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, your problem will be solved..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="ttttttttt "
    android:centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="@color/info_text_color"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: No resource identifier found for attribute 'centerInParent' in package 'android' :(

Comment: Try this.. I left out few words in it.
android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Answer (score 0):

go through it

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:text="ttttttttt "
    android:textColor="@color/info_text_color"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add this line into your button that's all.... This one is for your Relative layout

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

suppose you will use the linear layout means use this below

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="22dp"
android:padding="4dp" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/sub"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/center"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```